# jQuery Fancybox group images from SQL table

Tags: jquery, sql, fancybox

I got a little headache which I can't really find any solution for. Hopefully some of you can point me in right direction..

I'm looping out a table based on SQL data which also consist of 3 hidden pictures for each row. I want to create a gallery for each row and fire the fancybox with a single button. Only the 3 pictures related to that row should be shown.

Example picture:

> [image]

Only the last picture in SQL table are shown.

Fancybox function are working fine, it`s only about finding correct PHP/jQuery code.

Here is my code so far:

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.performance").fancybox();

});
```

HTML:

```
 <input type="button" rel='$value->ID' value="open fancybox"
    onclick='$("a.performance").trigger("click");' />
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(!$value->picture1 == '') {
    echo "<a class='performance' rel='$value->ID'  href='$value->picture1'></a>";
}
if(!$value->picture2 == ''){
    echo "<a class='performance' rel='$value->ID'  href='$value->picture2'></a>";
}
if(!$value->picture3 == '') {
    echo "<a class='performance' rel='$value->ID'  href='$value->picture3'></a>";
}
```

Comment: what is the specific problem? Are you aware that you have a mismatch of classes in jQuery selector and html?

Comment: Hi charlie..
Yes im aware of that.. Just a typo which i forgot to correct before posting.  
My problem is that even though all tables are stored whith link to three pictures, only one picture are shown.. the last 1 in last row.. does`t matter which button i press. same picture is loaded

Comment: what version of fancybox? why the button has the same `rel` attribute as the links? (is it part of the gallery?) If button should open the gallery from the first image, try `onclick='$("a.performance").eq(0).trigger("click");'`